# Why is NavigationLink not working inside of a SwiftUI alert?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I have an alert that upon tapping I would like to return the user back to another view. The alert is showing, but why does it not navigate upon tapping?

```
VStack{
  .alert("End of available content", isPresented: $model.alertIsPresented) {
    NavigationLink(destination: SearchView()) {
      Button("OK", role:.cancel) {}
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Because `NavigationLink` needs to be inside of a hierarchy using `NavigationView`. An `alert` is a modal presented outside of that structure.

Comment: Ah. Thank you. I should have asked: how do I transition the user to another view via an alert?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because NavigationLink needs to be inside of a hierarchy using NavigationView. An alert is a modal presented outside of that structure.

If you would like to programmatically navigate, you can use the `isActive` property of a `NavigationLink` within the `NavigationView` hierarchy.

```
struct ContentView : View {
    @State private var alertIsPresented = false
    @State private var navLinkActive = false
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack{
                Button("Present alert") {
                    alertIsPresented = true
                }
                .alert("End of available content", isPresented: $alertIsPresented) {
                    Button("Navigate") {
                        navLinkActive = true
                    }
                }
                NavigationLink(isActive: $navLinkActive, destination: { SearchView() }, label: {
                    EmptyView()
                })
            }
        }
    }
}

struct SearchView : View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("Search")
    }
}
```

Comment: If this answered your question, would you consider marking it as accepted?